# Ограничения репозитория гитхаб

Tags: github, github-pages

Если обратиться к [документации](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/), то там видно, что через сайт размер одного загружаемого файла не должен быть больше 25мб, а через консоль - 100мб. 
Это все ограничения по использованию гитхаба как хранилища? А общий размер репозитория - безграничен?

Comment: **https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/**

Comment: [**Тут ещё в подробностях**](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/84746/122122). Спасибо.